# Finding a point that is not inside any rotated rectangles

Tags: algorithm, intersection

I'm looking for an algorithm that can quickly (I'm heavily constrained by performance) find a point inside of a circle, where this point is outside of all rectangles in a provided set (these rectangles can be rotated). 
Or alternatively, to find a circle A with its center inside a circle B, where circle A does not intersect with a set of line segments.

The only solution I can come up with is to just loop through samples of points and then loop through the rectangles for each of them. But since my space is continuous, that's quite a pain.  I'm basically satisfied with just a single point that doesn't intersect, but there will be cases where no such points exist. In the latter case I would ideally try to find a point with the least amount of intersections, or be able to find the answer that no such point exists.

Does anyone know of any algorithms that can accomplish this in something less than O(n^2)? Anything that would help identify good candidate points would be awesome too.

A typical example of the situation is this: 
Lots of big rectangles, with  small circle in which I hope to find a point (here indicated with blue). It's common that many of the rectangles fall completely outside of the circle, and also common that the circle is completely covered. There's only a small set of lengths and widths that tend to be used for the rectangles.

[image]

Comment: Can you pre-process anything? And could you show a picture of what it would typically look like?

Comment: Added a typical picture to the OP.  There's very little preprocessing I think can do as the rectangles fluctuate all the time. Heavy calculations wouldn't really be possible either

Comment: If it would burn too much memory to just keep a fine grid (or better, quadtree) that records which grid cells are completely free of any rectangle, I would approximate the circle by a a polygon, and "clip" it against all nearby rectangles (you can use a much coarser grid to find all the rectangles you need to clip against).  If any area remains after clipping, you can choose any point in its interior (note that the average of its vertices is *not* necessarily guaranteed to be inside it, as the clipped remnant is not guaranteed to be convex, but this would be a nice choice when it does).

Comment: Hmm, can clipping be done in a way that allows good performance? Would have to at least account for the circle being split into two

Comment: I think your best option would be to use a coarse grid to detect all nearby rectangles, then make a fine grid that is just large enough to contain the "rasterised" circle and "rasterise" all those nearby rectangles onto it; any cell in this fine grid that has been "painted" by the circle but not by any nearby rectangle is a valid point.  Graphics cards manage to do essentially this many times per second -- you could probably do this on a GPU too.

Comment: Sounds like that might be a workable solution in some cases. Unfortunately probably still too heavy of one for mine, as figuring out what part sof the grid to color per rectangle sounds like its not too different from having a bunch of points for which you check if they're contained in rectangles.

Comment: Note, you probably want to read this and see the many references: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_operations_on_polygons
It's likely a sweepline algorithm would be state-of-the-art for this particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably several interesting ways to do this. The simplest algorithm I can think of that gives a decent runtime is an algorithm as follows:

1. Treat all rectangles as a set of line segments.
2. Use an efficient algorithm to find the intersection of all line segments (for example the [Bentley-Ottmann algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bentley%E2%80%93Ottmann_algorithm).)
3. Create a list of points of interest (POIs) that are either a) the corners of a rectangle or b) the intersection points computed in 2.
4. Create a finer set of line segments such that each line segment terminates at a POI defined in 3.
5. Using the POIs and the finer set of line segments from 4, compute a constrained triangulation (for example a [Constrained Delaunay Triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constrained_Delaunay_triangulation).)
6. Pick any (unlabeled) triangle to start. Determine if the triangle lies within at least one rectangle (label it as a COVERED triangle) or not (label it as a FREE triangle). To do this you can use any [point in polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) algorithm, for example ray-casting.
7. Run a Depth or Breadth first search starting at this triangle and expanding to neighbors, taking care not to cross between any triangle pair that would require crossing a line segment defined in 4. For every triangle visited, label it as the same label as the starting triangle.
8. Repeat 6-7 until all triangles are labeled (or all triangles covering the circle of interest are labeled.)

The union of all FREE triangles intersected with the circled of interest yields precisely the points that are not covered by any rectangle and are within the circle.

Note, this algorithm is a bit general and can be improved by focusing only in the area around the circle (for example a bounding box region can only be considered, with the bounding box encompassing all rectangles intersecting the circle.)

To analyze the runtime, consider the runtime of each key step:

- 2. has a runtime of O((n+k) log n) where k is the number of intersections, where n is the number of line segments.
- 5. has a runtime of O(m log m) where m is the number of POIs, m is O(n+k)
- 6. and 7. should be analyzed together. In the worst case, each triangle would need O(n) computations to check for containment in a rectangle. Given that there would be O(m) triangles this would yield a O(nm) bound. However, the purpose of the triangulation is to reuse the point in polygon computation for the seeding triangle to label as many neighboring triangles as possible. In practice the number of triangles that would require a point in polygon computation should be negligible. Therefore the runtime of this step is O(tn) where t is the number of traingles for which point in polygon computations are performed.

The runtime expected is, therefore, O((n+k) log n + t(n+k)) where k is the number of intersections in step 2 and t is the number of triangles for which point in polygon computations are performed. In the worst case this is O(n^2 log n) as you can create a pathological example with n^2 intersections, but this should be unlikely if not possible. Likewise, the number t should be kept to a minimum to make this as efficient as possible. If both t << n and k << n^2, this would be quite efficient.

One approximation that could yield performance improvement:

- Consider approximating the circle by a set of `r` line segments, and including these line segments in steps 1-5. While this is an approximation, it would potentially improve the runtime, as only triangles inside the circle would ever need to be considered.